# Using Google Vision annotation in a streaming fashion

Tags: bash, stream, base64, akka-stream, google-cloud-vision

Trying to use Google`s CloudVision [images.annotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate) with Akka-HTTP, images coming as streams, http chunked responses. Instead of collecting the whole image, then encoding it with Base64 and only then sending JSON request for annotation, I encode image chunks and send encoded chunks concatenated in the request.

Couldn't find an existing Akka-Streams ready fast implementation for encoding streams with Base64. Fortunately, Base64 is designed to be OK with decoding concatenated encoded parts of the original sequence. But CloudVision doesn't accept that:

```
base64 --version
#base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.30

ipfs get QmfUQT8FnKY4ZbymvfEMPptFughPgcVi9ahUbrPzhBeavb --output base64_encoded_chunks
ipfs get QmfQpPo5ag4dRtuB9uJLwyc8Z3W3vQr5qMRud4YB2KZFWp --output original_image
base64 -w 0 original_image > base64_encoded_whole

# now both base64 encoded files can be decoded into original file contents:
cat base64_encoded_chunks| base64 -d | shasum
# 7c446d90e78baf9511fbf6e9cfad80139f7b708e  -
cat base64_encoded_whole | base64 -d | shasum 
# 7c446d90e78baf9511fbf6e9cfad80139f7b708e  -
shasum original_image                     
# 7c446d90e78baf9511fbf6e9cfad80139f7b708e  original_image

echo '{"requests":[{"image":{"content": "' > ./request_prefix
echo '"},"features":[{"type":"LABEL_DETECTION"}]}]}' > ./request_suffix

ANNOTATE_URL=https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
annotate(){ cat request_prefix $1 request_suffix | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$ANNOTATE_URL?key=$API_KEY" --data-binary @- }

#using the sequence encoded 'in one go' with base64 utility 
#it's accepted by Google Vision, getting a response with labels
annotate base64_encoded_whole
#  "responses": [
#    {
#      "labelAnnotations": [
#        {
#          "mid": "/m/03q69",
#          "description": "hair",
#          "score": 0.9692406,
#          "topicality": 0.9692406
#        },
#   ...

#using concatenated base64-encoded chunks of the original sequence
#despite the fact that it's decoded exactly to original sequence with base64 utility
#Google Vision can't decode it
annotate base64_encoded_chunks
#{
#  "error": {
#    "code": 400,
#    "message": "Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.content' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"\n/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA...
```

I'm aware of workarounds like "don't stream that" or "adapt a Base64 implementation to Akka-Streams", but the question is:

**[Q]** Is it some limitation/bug of Base64 decoding in CloudVision, or is my way of using Base64 wrong?

Comment: This is not publicly documented in any way and I think it's worth raising in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433), either as a feature request or as a bug. I'm with google cloud support and I can do this on your behalf, however, I'd suggest that you first share here more details regarding how you produce the encoded chunks.

Comment: Thanks @LefterisS, I'll definitely add more details. Had a lengthy discussion with other folks from cloud support, so I have a very thorough description of the issue already. To me it looks like a bug at the moment, but only because it's not mentioned in the docs. Otherwise it's a feature request - taking care of processing wider range of base64 encoded sequences would be very liberating - users of the service could be less constrained in their encoding ways and I believe it'd even enable streaming.

Comment: I think that what's most important to file a complete issue is to include the code you're using to produce the chunks, if that's not around then I believe that the Vision engineers will go ahead and ask it anyway.